# I got an error when calling kmodes module in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When calling the kmodes package like this:

```py
# I have also tried
# from kmodes.kmodes import KModes
from kmodes.kprototypes import KPrototypes
```

```c
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kmodes'
```

Comment: looks like you don't have `kmodes` package installed. Try installing from pip with `pip install kmodes` on a terminal

Comment: Thank you, I thought I had but it turns out I didn't. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @648trindade, all I had to do was install the package. That's not included in Anaconda by default.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. It turned out that I named my test file as kmodes.py, and current directory is in sys.path. so python use my test file as the library.

If you have set the system path to some folder having kmodes.py file, just rename your script as something else, everything is fine.

Or you just remove the sys.path line from the code and restart the compiler